# Degree of an entity

Tags: primary-key, database

If the degree of an entity is 8, what is the minimum number of attributes required to form the primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Degree is dependent upon their relationship. Suppose, there is a binary relationship; means between two entities their degree is two. Suppose, there is ternary relationship; means between three entities there degree is three. Suppose, there are many entities at the time of relationship; then the degree is many.

Answer (score 0):

Entitys don;t have "degree".  What you may be referring to is the Degree of a relationship, and what is sometimes referred to as a "Dgeree of an Entity" relationship.  If this is what you are asking about then the "Degree of a Relationship" in an RDBMS is the count of entities involved in that relationship.

i.e., in a relationship between a product and the store that carries it, there are two entities (product and Store) and so it is a binary relationship (Degree = 2)  In a relationship between vendor and store, there could be three entities involved (vendor, product, and store)  so this would be a ternary relationship (Degree=3)

In general RDBMS do not model ternary or higher degree relationships directly, they require that you implement them with multiple binary relationships (in e.g., you would need Vendor-> Product  and Product-> Store relationships...

Comment: I expect the OP means the degree (arity) of a *relation*, i.e. the number of attributes it has. RDBMSs certainly can and do model directly relationships of *any* degree - n-degree relationships are represented by n-degree relations.

Answer (score 0):

In principle the minimum number of attributes needed to form a primary key of any relation is zero. It is perfectly possible (though relatively unusual) to have a key consisting of zero attributes. A relation variable with a key consisting of no attributes is limited to one tuple at most.